# How to add x days to a date returned from datepicker's getDate() and return in specific date format?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to add some days to a date returned by a jQuery datepicker field and then put it in an easy to read date format.

I have this code:

```
var end = $("#to-date").datepicker("getDate");
```

Returns:

`Tue May 12 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)`

I want to add 3 days to that date and then get that date returned in another date format.

I add the extra days:

```
console.log( end.getDate() + 3 );
```

Returns:

`15` (3 days from the 12th)

I was expecting this to be

`Fri May 15 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)`

The end result I am looking for is to get the date in a `dd/mm/yy` format after adding days to an existing date.

Is this possible with `getDate()`?

Comment: `.getDate()` + `.setDate()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+add+days

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add days to JavaScript Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date)

Comment: `.getDate()` gets the day of the month (an integer), adding 3 to this won't give you a full date https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate it's another example of javascript's really badly named methods

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getTime` function it will provide your date into milliseconds. Add total milliseconds for 3 days (i.e. 3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) into this `getTime` value and convert into `date` again.

Test it below.

```js
let start = new Date();
console.log(start);

let end = new Date(start.getTime() + (3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
console.log(end);
```